# Inversion of rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

For example, I have a two-dimensional rotation matrix
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5091 &           -0.8607 \\
    0.8607 & \phantom{-}0.5091
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and I have a vector I'd like to rotate, e.g. $(1, -0.5)$.

My problem is to find an inverse of the rotation matrix so that I can later “undo” the rotation performed on the vector so that I get back the original vector.

The rotation matrix is not parametric, created via eigendecomposition, I can't use angles to easily create an inverse matrix.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Recall that [**rotation matrices**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) are orthogonal therefore

$$A^{-1}=A^T$$

indeed note that

$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(-\alpha) & -\sin(-\alpha)\\ \sin(-\alpha) & \cos(-\alpha)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha \\ -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}=A^T$$

Comment: @aleksv I've also added a simple way to see that assuming the opposite angle. You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

That's easy:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha \\ \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha \\ -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$